# how to create a login form at top right of page using HTML?

Tags: html

How can I create a login form for example to look like this:

Banner -------------------------------  Email/user name           Password

```
                                    Remember me (tick here)    forgotten?
```

I want it to be a bit similar to this website https://similarworlds.com/ login form.

Do I need to use a specific code ? and if so where in my current HTML code do I need to put it?

Comment: The html syntax for making a login system is <form>. You should format it to be in the top right with CSS (One idea is to put it into a <div> and then set the right side margin to ~50 and left to auto). You might need some kind of server-side language like PHP to process the data which was sent by the form. There should be a lot of online tutorials for this kind of stuff. Make sure you research a lot more. Here's a place to start: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know how divide the page in frame, next you could create a login form. The link in the comment, that ZeBirdeh post, explain all.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put the form in a div and then align it to left.